# ANOVA Resampling with Welch Correction

Tags: r, permutation, anova, resampling

I'm doing some exploring with the same data and I'm trying to highlight the in-group variance versus the between group variance. Now I have been able to successfully show the between group variance is very strong, however, the nature of the data should show weak within group variance. (I.e. My Shapiro-Wilk normality test shows this) I believe if I do some re-sampling with a welch correction, this might be the case.

I was wondering if someone knew if there was a re-sampling based anova with a Welch correction in R. I see there is an R implementation of the permutation test but with no correction. If not, how would I code the test directly while using this implementation. 
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/lmPerm/html/aovp.html

Here is the outline for my basic between group ANOVA:

```
fit <- lm(formula = data$Boys ~ data$GroupofBoys)
anova(fit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're correct in that there isn't an easy way to do welch corrected anova with resampling, but it should be possible to hobble a few things together to make it work.

```
require('Ecdat')
```

I'll use the “Star” dataset from the “Ecdat" package which looks at the effects of small class sizes on standardized test scores.

```
star<-Star
attach(star)

head(star)

        tmathssk treadssk  classk      totexpk sex  freelunk race  schidkn
2       473      447       small.class       7 girl       no white      63
3       536      450       small.class      21 girl       no black      20
5       463      439 regular.with.aide       0  boy      yes black      19
11      559      448           regular      16  boy       no white      69
12      489      447       small.class       5  boy      yes white      79
13      454      431           regular       8  boy      yes white       5
```

Some exploratory analysis:

```
#bloxplots 
boxplot(treadssk ~ classk, ylab="Total Reading Scaled Score")
title("Reading Scores by Class Size")
```

[image]

```
#histograms
hist(treadssk, xlab="Total Reading Scaled Score")
```

[image]

Run regular anova

```
model1 = aov(treadssk ~ classk, data = star)
summary(model1)

              Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
classk         2   37201   18601   18.54 9.44e-09 ***
Residuals   5745 5764478    1003                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

A look at the anova residuals

```
#qqplot
qqnorm(residuals(model1),ylab="Reading Scaled Score")
qqline(residuals(model1),ylab="Reading Scaled Score")
```

[image]

qqplot shows that ANOVA residuals deviate from the normal qqline

```
#Fitted Y vs. Residuals
plot(fitted(model1), residuals(model1))
```

[image]

Fitted Y vs. Residuals shows converging trend in the residuals, can test with a Shapiro-Wilk test just to be sure

```
shapiro.test(treadssk[1:5000]) #shapiro.test contrained to sample sizes between 3 and 5000

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  treadssk[1:5000]
W = 0.92256, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Just confirms that we aren't going to be able to assume a normal distribution.

We can use bootstrap to estimate the true F-dist.

```
#Bootstrap version (with 10,000 iterations)
mean_read = mean(treadssk)
grpA = treadssk[classk=="regular"] - mean_read[1]
grpB = treadssk[classk=="small.class"]  - mean_read[2]
grpC = treadssk[classk=="regular.with.aide"]  - mean_read[3]
sim_classk <- classk
R = 10000
sim_Fstar = numeric(R)
for (i in 1:R) {
  groupA = sample(grpA, size=2000, replace=T)
  groupB = sample(grpB, size=1733, replace=T)
  groupC = sample(grpC, size=2015, replace=T)
  sim_score = c(groupA,groupB,groupC)
  sim_data = data.frame(sim_score,sim_classk)
}
```

Now we need to get the set of unique pairs of the Group factor

```
allPairs <- expand.grid(levels(sim_data$sim_classk), levels(sim_data$sim_classk))
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-combination-of-two-columns-in-r/28574136#28574136
allPairs <- unique(t(apply(allPairs, 1, sort)))
allPairs <- allPairs[ allPairs[,1] != allPairs[,2], ]

allPairs
     [,1]                [,2]               
[1,] "regular"           "small.class"      
[2,] "regular"           "regular.with.aide"
[3,] "regular.with.aide" "small.class"
```

Since oneway.test() applies a Welch correction by default, we can use that on our simulated data.

```
allResults <- apply(allPairs, 1, function(p) {
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587498/post-hoc-tests-for-one-way-anova-with-welchs-correction-in-r
  dat <- sim_data[sim_data$sim_classk %in% p, ]
  ret <- oneway.test(sim_score ~ sim_classk, data = sim_data, na.action = na.omit)
  ret$sim_classk <- p
  ret
})

length(allResults)
[1] 3


allResults[[1]]

One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  sim_score and sim_classk
F = 1.7741, num df = 2.0, denom df = 1305.9, p-value = 0.170
```