# Duplicate combination of values in columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-combination-of-two-columns-in-r/), I have a data frame and would like to extract the rows that are not unique in their combination of values in several specific columns.

E.g., I have a data frame df:

```
> df<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4),c(T,F,T,T),c("a","b","c","b"),c("b","d","e","a"))
> df
     [,1] [,2]    [,3] [,4]
[1,] "1"  "TRUE"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "2"  "FALSE" "b"  "d" 
[3,] "3"  "TRUE"  "c"  "e" 
[4,] "4"  "TRUE"  "b"  "a"
```

I would like to test whether the combination of values in coumn 2, 3 and 4 is unique or duplicate for the rows of the data frame. However, I don't want to classify the first occurence of a combination as unique and all subsequent combinations as duplicates but rather **all occurences of non-unique combinations as duplicates**.

In this example, rows 1 and 4 are duplicates and rows 2 and 3 are unique in their combinations of values in columns 2, 3 and 4.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your data.frame is a matrix.  Use `data.frame` instead of `cbind` to create a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We `sort` the columns 3:4 in the 'df' by row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, transpose (`t`) it  and assign the output to the corresponding columns.  To get the logical index of all the duplicates, we can apply `duplicated` in the default direction and in reverse direction using `fromLast=TRUE`.  Here, I assumed that the first column will not be used for considering the duplicate elements.

```
df[3:4] <- t(apply(df[3:4], 1, sort))
duplicated(df[-1])|duplicated(df[-1], fromLast=TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, though I had to get rid of reassigning the columns 3 and 4 in order to keep my data frame in its current form.

Comment: @atreju In that case, you can create a new dataframe and then do the duplicated `dfN <- cbind(df[2],t(apply(df[3:4], 1, sort)));
 duplicated(dfN)|duplicated(dfN, fromLast=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using dplyr. It uses all combinations of rows and checks if all the elements of one row belong to another row. In the end instead of True/False you get a number for each row that represents how many times it was found to match with other rows. It will be more obvious if you run the script step by step.

```
df<-data.frame(x1 =c(1,2,3,4),
               x2 = c(T,F,T,T),
               x3 = c("a","b","c","b"),
               x4 = c("b","d","e","a"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)


df %>%                                                                                
  rowwise() %>%                                                                     # for each row
  do(data.frame(., df2=df, stringsAsFactors=F)) %>%                                 # combine each row with all rows of dataset
  filter(x1 != df2.x1) %>%                                                          # exclude cases of self combinations
  rowwise() %>%                                                                     # for each row combination
  mutate(match = 
           ifelse(sum(c(x2,x3,x4) %in% c(df2.x2, df2.x3, df2.x4))==3, 1, 0)) %>%    # flag a match when all 3 elements of one row belong to the elements of the other row 
  group_by(x1,x2,x3,x4) %>%                                                         # group by rows of initial dataset
  summarise(sum_match = sum(match)) %>%                                             # calculate how many times they match with other rows
  ungroup


#   x1    x2 x3 x4 sum_match
# 1  1  TRUE  a  b         1
# 2  2 FALSE  b  d         0
# 3  3  TRUE  c  e         0
# 4  4  TRUE  b  a         1
```