# Sampling a graph in R

Tags: r, graph, reproducible-research

I want to make a directed graph in R by making 2 data frame: one for vertices and one for edges. Also, my graph should have these attributes:

- No circle (therefore no A -> A)
- There is maximum 1 edge between 2 nodes.

I come up with the code as below:

```
library(dplyr)

USER_BASE <- 1:100
MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP = length(USER_BASE)*4

my_random <- function(vector, size, replace, seed)
{
    set.seed(seed)
    return(sample(vector, size = size, replace = replace))
}

user <- data.frame(
    id = USER_BASE
)

relationship <- data.frame(
    from = my_random(USER_BASE, MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP, replace = TRUE, 1),
    to = my_random(USER_BASE, MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP, replace = TRUE, 2)
) %>% filter(from != to) %>% unique()
```

My code still allows 2 edges between 2 nodes (A -> B AND B -> A). How could I achieve that only 1 edge between A and B?

Kind regards

Edit: I found a solution from: 
[Unique rows, considering two columns, in R, without order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-combination-of-two-columns-in-r)

My complete code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

USER_BASE <- 1:100
MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP = length(USER_BASE)*4

my_random <- function(vector, size, replace, seed)
{
    set.seed(seed)
    return(sample(vector, size = size, replace = replace))
}

user <- data.frame(
    id = USER_BASE
)

relationship <- data.frame(
    from = my_random(USER_BASE, MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP, replace = TRUE, 1),
    to = my_random(USER_BASE, MAXIMUM_USER_RELATIONSHIP, replace = TRUE, 2)
) %>% filter(from != to) %>% unique()

relationship <- unique(as.data.table(relationship)[, c("from", "to") := list(pmin(from, to),
                                                 pmax(from, to))], by = c("from", "to"))
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-combination-of-two-columns-in-r

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: I already posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `anti_join` to remove any rows which exist in an reversed version.

```
reverse <- data.frame(to = relationship$from, from = relationship$to)

anti_join(relationship, reverse)
```