# Making groups of paired entries according to shared elements

Tags: r, grouping, data-manipulation

I am a student trying to analyse factors that increase the probability of livestock killing by predators in Northern Indian landscape. In order to do so I need a list of covariate that I will use for my final logistic regression model. The question I am posing is related to one of my covariates - the number of recurrent livestock killings. 
A recurrent event is defined as a kill that takes place less than 500meters and within 7 days of the *preceding kill*. (Note - emphasis on *preceding kill*. This is because a group of recurrent events can extend longer than 7 days or beyond the 500m threshold so long as the space between each kill is at most 7 days or 500m)
I  have a dataset that includes the following - GPS coordinates of kill location, date of kill, predator and prey species. For this question, only the date and location of kill is relevant. 
This is an example of my raw data

```
    rawq <- structure(list(long = c(79.31957, 79.86758, 79.32283, 79.32253, 79.30502, 79.30047, 79.19935, 79.1984, 79.1984, 79.19318, 79.19247, 79.19243, 79.18512, 79.18333, 79.1541, 79.14438, 79.13998, 79.13538, 79.12522, 79.10168, 79.04163, 79.0405, 79.0364, 79.03505, 79.03473, 79.03428, 79.02517, 79.02458, 79.02428, 79.02265, 79.0197, 79.0197, 79.01967, 79.01965, 79.0193, 79.019, 79.01873, 79.0187, 79.0181, 79.01775, 79.00998, 79.00907, 79.00692, 79.00655, 79.0057, 79.00565, 79.00463, 79.00462, 79.00453, 79.00427, 79.0041, 79.00222, 79.00117, 79.00088, 79.00073, 78.9928, 78.9888, 78.98878, 78.98877, 78.9887, 78.98542, 78.98523, 78.9852, 78.98445, 78.97907, 78.9775, 78.9761, 78.97607, 78.97537, 78.97432, 78.97393, 78.97343, 78.97083, 78.95655, 78.9394, 78.92815, 78.92353, 78.92353, 78.92353, 78.92088, 78.92045, 78.91933, 78.91738, 78.90997, 78.90223, 78.90013, 78.90013, 78.88645, 78.8856, 78.8856, 78.8856, 78.88557, 78.86903, 78.86765, 78.85663, 78.8562, 78.85588, 78.8548, 78.83507, 78.80902), 
                           lat = c(29.3684, 29.35495, 29.39068, 29.3907, 29.34828, 29.30717, 29.26702, 29.25967, 29.25967, 29.2672, 29.25588, 29.25588, 29.46787, 29.34175, 29.42, 29.42098, 29.41918, 29.34048, 29.49228, 29.53947, 29.37597, 29.37652, 29.3591, 29.35055, 29.31765, 29.37003, 29.3125, 29.35305, 29.40163, 29.39007, 29.37155, 29.35098, 29.35515, 29.35517, 29.37277, 29.37068, 29.37345, 29.36962, 29.32252, 29.37657, 29.35432, 29.37653, 29.38792, 29.36958, 29.36803, 29.36808, 29.33892, 29.37277, 29.36908, 29.36773, 29.34068, 29.40667, 29.3076, 29.40875, 29.32183, 29.4093, 29.4075, 29.40742, 29.40738, 29.35965, 29.36952, 29.35965, 29.35967, 29.39118, 29.38528, 29.36535, 29.3598, 29.3598, 29.40777, 29.36418, 29.30988, 29.37605, 29.36813, 29.30137, 29.40247, 29.40767, 29.40455, 29.40455, 29.40455, 29.4092, 29.40532, 29.35217, 29.40328, 29.4023, 29.38242, 29.37243, 29.37243, 29.37205, 29.36975, 29.36975, 29.36975, 29.36972, 29.3721, 29.37023, 29.36867, 29.38953, 29.36808, 29.36865, 29.3841, 29.35162), 
        Cattle.sp. = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        .Label = c("Boffalo(Calf)", "Buffalo", "Buffalo(Calf)", "BufFalo(Calf)", "Buffalo(S/A/)", "Bullack(S/A/)", "Bullock", "Bullock(S,A/)", "Bullock(S/A)", "Bullock(S/A/)", "Cow", "Cow (Calf)", "Cow(calf)", "Cow(Calf)", "Cow(S/A)", "Cow(S/A/)", "Horse"), class "factor"), 
        Predator = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        .Label = c("Leopard", "Tiger"), class = "factor"), 
        Date = structure(c(16891, 17036, 17141, 17141, 16833, 16898, 16845, 16845, 16845, 17125, 17125, 17125, 17005, 17100, 17015, 16813, 16886, 17064, 17096, 16937, 17070, 17101, 17020, 17079, 17164, 16993, 16958, 17010, 17132, 17075, 17023, 17010, 16975, 16975, 16987, 17121, 17054, 17090, 16938, 16984, 16928, 16967, 16927, 16967, 17084, 16975, 16975, 16927, 16975, 16972, 16977, 16928, 17020, 17030, 16979, 16822, 17087, 17156, 17156, 17114, 16959, 17400, 17035, 17037, 17056, 16845, 16984, 16984, 16961, 16861, 17100, 17010, 17034, 16823, 17039, 16819, 16968, 16968, 16968, 16802, 16942, 17098, 16975, 16975, 16836, 17138, 17138, 16808, 16936, 16941, 16949, 16949, 16986, 16986, 16986, 16914, 16925, 16884, 17130, 17041), class = "Date")), 
        .Names = c("long", "lat", "Cattle.sp.", "Predator", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following code, to first generate pairwise distance matrices for both distance and time respectively. I produced a table coloc.distance which consisted all the pairs of points less than 500m away from each other. I then selected the rows in which time was less than 7 days. To produce the final table consisting of all the pairs of points for which distance < 500m AND time < 7days.

```
    raw = read.csv("newraw.csv", header = T)
    library(measurements)
    library(fossil)                                    
    library(data.table)

    raw$Date <- as.Date(raw$Date)                            #formatting date


    a = as.matrix(dist(raw$Date))                              #generate pairwise distance matrix
    m <- as.matrix(earth.dist(raw))                             #pairwise distances

   sep.km <- 0.5                                               #threshold distance

   coloc.distance <- data.table(which(m<sep.km, arr.ind=T))    #choose 
   all pairs for which distance falls under threshold
   setnames(coloc.distance,c("row","col"),c("SD.1","SD.2"))    #adjust names
   coloc.distance <- coloc.distance[SD.1<SD.2,]                #lower triangular matrix
   coloc.distance[,dist:=m[SD.1,SD.2], by="SD.1,SD.2"] 
   coloc.distance[,time:=a[SD.1,SD.2], by="SD.1,SD.2"] 
   killsite <- data.table(id=as.integer(rownames(raw)),raw)
   setkey(coloc.distance,SD.1)
   coloc.distance[killsite,c("long.1","lat.1"):=list(long,lat)]
   setkey(coloc.distance,SD.2)
   coloc.distance[killsite,c("long.2","lat.2"):=list(long,lat)]
   setkey(coloc.distance, SD.1)
   coloc.distance[killsite, "date.1":=list(Date)]
   setkey(coloc.distance, SD.2)
   coloc.distance[killsite,"date.2" :=list(Date)]

   finalrows <- data.table(which(coloc.distance$time<7, arr.ind = T))

   final <- coloc.distance[finalrows$V1,]
   print(final)
```

My problem is that I don't just want pairs of recurrent events. In some instances there are more than one or two recurrent events. I need a way to sort pairs with shared points into groups. 
For example, if my code returns the following pairs -

[1,2][1,3][4,5][6,7][3,8]

the groups I would assign are [1,2,3,8] and [4,5]. Is there a function that would make these groups automatically. It is clear that 8 is also related to 1 and 2 because it is related to 3.

For the dataframe "final" from the code above, these are the output data that I would hope to recieve

This is the final dataframe generated by the code for the first 50 entries

```
final <- structure(list(SD.1 = c(3L, 8L, 11L, 33L, 35L, 46L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 47L, 58L), 
                        SD.2 = c(4L, 9L, 12L, 34L, 40L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 59L), 
                        dist = c(0.0291582094908988, 0, 0.00388155718182341, 0.00295090125908757, 0.448566716059333, 0.155426365139648, 0.301966362430361, 0.139316330866369, 0.152255819956674, 0.202390901062769, 0.00455334236486617), 
                        time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 3, 2, 0), 
                        long.1 = c(79.32283, 79.1984, 79.19247, 79.01967, 79.0193, 79.00565, 79.00655, 79.00565, 79.00453, 79.00463, 78.98878), 
                        lat.1 = c(29.39068, 29.25967, 29.25588, 29.35515, 29.37277, 29.36808, 29.36958, 29.36808, 29.36908, 29.33892, 29.40742), 
                        long.2 = c(79.32253, 79.1984, 79.19243, 79.01965, 79.01775, 79.00453, 79.00427, 79.00427, 79.00427, 79.0041, 78.98877), 
                        lat.2 = c(29.3907, 29.25967, 29.25588, 29.35517, 29.37657, 29.36908, 29.36773, 29.36773, 29.36773, 29.34068, 29.40738), 
                        date.1 = structure(c(17141, 16845, 17125, 16975, 16987, 16975,16967, 16975, 16975, 16975, 17156), class = "Date"), 
                        date.2 = structure(c(17141, 16845, 17125, 16975, 16984, 16975, 16972, 16972, 16972, 16977, 17156), class = "Date")), 
                        .Names = c("SD.1", "SD.2", "dist", "time", "long.1", "lat.1", "long.2", "lat.2", "date.1", "date.2"), 
                        sorted = "SD.2", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

As you can see there are 11 pairs in this table -

[3,4] [8,9] [11,12] [33,34] [35,40] [46,49] [44,50] [46,50] [49,50] [47,51] [58,59]

A sufficient output is as follows -

[3,4] [8,9] [11,12] [33,34] [35,40] [44,46,49,50] [58,59]

Within this limited dataset, there is only one group with more than 2 events. Of course, in my larger set, there are many more. This was just the most readily available set.

Comment: Can you provide some data for the `killsite` object? I can read in your example data as an object called `raw`, then run your code until the line `coloc.distance[killsite,c("long.1","lat.1"):=list(long,lat)]` where it fails because the object `killsite` cannot be found.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to define it over here. Try running the code now. Sorry about that

Comment: Great! Can you also change `final <- coloc.distance[final$V1,]` to `final <- coloc.distance[finalrows$V1,]` to get that bit working correctly?

Comment: Can you also update your example data so that it actually produces pairs that have the problem you are describing? Your current example data doesn't return any pairs with shared values.

Comment: All done. There should be enough value now.

Comment: Thanks for updating the example data. I have it working, but the example data only has one group of shared points. Is that how your real data is or do you have more than one group of shared points? If so, can you update your example data again so I can retest my code?

Comment: Hi, updated example data to include, 100 kill sites. This should include a few more groups

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dataset called `final` provided in your question, here is one solution that gets to the output desired. I use underscores to show the combinations rather than list-style just for simplicity.

I've added the desired output as a column called `newgroup` in the `final` dataframe, but you can take it out as a vector using `dplyr::pull(newgroup)`.

First, identify which sites appear more than once, and so should be grouped. Store these in a vector called `combo_group`

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

combo_group <- 
    final %>% 
    filter(duplicated(SD.1) | duplicated(SD.1, fromLast = T) | duplicated(SD.2) | duplicated(SD.2, fromLast = T)) %>% 
    select(SD.1, SD.2) %>% 
    combine() %>% 
    unique() %>% 
    sort()
```

The vector looks like this:

```
combo_group
[1] 44 46 49 50
```

Second, create the `newgroup` column that combines the shared sites whenever there is a row that shares a site.

```
final %<>% 
    mutate(newgroup = ifelse(((SD.1 %in% combo_group)|(SD.2 %in% combo_group)), paste(combo_group, collapse = "_"), paste(SD.1, SD.2, sep = "_")))
```

This returns a dataframe called `final` with 11 rows and 11 columns. The relevant variables look like this:

```
final %>% select(SD.1, SD.2, newgroup)
   SD.1 SD.2    newgroup
1     3    4         3_4
2     8    9         8_9
3    11   12       11_12
4    33   34       33_34
5    35   40       35_40
6    46   49 44_46_49_50
7    44   50 44_46_49_50
8    46   50 44_46_49_50
9    49   50 44_46_49_50
10   47   51       47_51
11   58   59       58_59
```

Comment: @DhruvModi I am not sure this solution will work if there are multiple groups of shared sites, but it's a start. I can update this answer, if needed, once more example data showing the grouping problem is provided.

Comment: Hey, apologies. I actually updated the initial set of raw values "rawq" to include an expanded list of entries. I didn't want to overcrowd the dataset "final" because I needed it to exemplify my point. It seems like there is an issue for the expanded dataset. Not sure why its happening, but the code appears to be combining all the combo_groups into one large group. I ran it at first with my entire set, and got one huge group with all combo_groups merged together while all the groups with only to sites were intact.

Comment: I thought that this may be due to the fact that the recurrence criteria are to general and expand to include a lot of the data under one group, but then I tried it with a set of 100 kill sites which I manually sorted into two combo groups as well as 12 pairs. Instead, I got one large group consisting of the two combo groups and the 12 pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @DhruvModi Ah, I had thought that would happen. I think this requires a bespoke function to grab the different combinations and then assign them. I will think further later today. In the meantime, here is one of my questions that was somewhat similar and had a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009055/select-rows-based-on-non-directed-combinations-of-columns