# Subset by row and column reciprocity

Tags: r, duplicates

I am having trouble subsetting a data.frame based on reciprocity of values in row and column.

Here is a example df to illustrate the problem:

```
rater <- c(21, 23, 26, 24)
ratee <- c(24, 21, 23, 21)
rating.data <- data.frame(rater, ratee)
```

Output:

```
   rater ratee
1    21    24
2    23    21
3    26    23
4    24    21
```

I would like to subset this df by only keeping the rows that have reciprocal values.

The resulting subset should look like this:

```
   rater ratee
1    21    24
4    24    21
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: You using the word reciprocal wrongly. 1/x is the reciprocal value of x.

Comment: do you want to end up with a symmetric matrix???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-rows-considering-two-columns-in-r-without-order also check the link

Comment: I have a matrix from using the igraph package, an adjacency matrix. That package can only provide a ratio of the reciprocal values. I am using the language they used for network analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
library(dplyr)
rating.data %>% inner_join(.,.,by=c("rater" = "ratee","ratee"="rater"))
```

Or this, for some reason it's twice faster on your small example (though slower than akrun's solution):

```
merge(rating.data,setNames(rating.data,rev(names(rating.data))))
```

to keep the second solution flexible with your additional columns:

```
merge(rating.data,setNames(rating.data[,c("rater","ratee")],c("ratee","rater")))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I was looking for as I did not want to loose the rest of the df. This allows me to specify the columns I have in mind. Thank you for reading my mind!

Comment: You're welcome, akrun's solution could easily be adapted though, if you just put `rating.data[,c("rater","ratee")]` in the first line, it might be faster too if it's a concern.

Answer (score 9):

We could sort by row and then use `duplicated`

```
m1 <- t(apply(rating.data, 1, sort))
rating.data[duplicated(m1)|duplicated(m1, fromLast = TRUE),]
#   rater ratee
#1    21    24
#4    24    21
```

Comment: This is great! I have been trying to think of how to use duplicated in for the problem. This works well! Thank you!

Comment: @SeekingData  if this answer help you , you can accept it  :)

Comment: I wish I could accept both. Thank you, Akrun!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
N=10#number of rows 
dt1<-data.table(a=1:N,b=sample(N))#create the data.table that holds the info

dt1[,d:=ifelse(a<b,paste0(a,"_",b),paste0(b,"_",a))]#create unique key per pair  respecting the rule "min_max"
setkey(dt1,d)#setting the key 
dt1[dt1[,.N,d][N!=1],.(a,b)] #keep only the pairs that appear more than once
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pmin` and `pmax` to assist with grouping and then filter on all groups having more than one entry, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = paste0(pmin(rater, ratee), pmax(rater, ratee))) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>   rater ratee
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1    21    24
> 2    24    21
> ```

Comment: I thought about the `pmin/pmax` approach.  It would be faster

Answer (score 1):

Similar in spirit to akrun's method, `rbind` the data.frame to a copy with the columns reversed. find duplicates, starting from the bottom, which will then return TRUE for the rows in the original data.frame. Subset this logical vector with `[seq_len(nrow(rating.data))]` to return a vector of the appropriate length to `[` in order to subset on the rows.

```
rating.data[duplicated(rbind(rating.data,
                             unname(unclass(rating.data[2:1]))),
                       fromLast=TRUE)[seq_len(nrow(rating.data))],]
  rater ratee
1    21    24
4    24    21
```