# Retrieving a data frame of unique records based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I am using the pairwise_cor function to generate word correlations in text.  The problem is, the output contains duplicate rows when taking into account the combination of two columns.  I want to filter out the duplicated rows.

Here is an extremely simplified example:

```
item1 <- c("dog", "cat", "horse", "cow", "chicken", "sheep")
item2 <- c("cat", "dog", "cow", "horse", "sheep", "chicken")
correlation <- c(2,2,3,3,4,4)

df <- cbind.data.frame(item1, item2, correlation)
df


    item1   item2 correlation
1     dog     cat     2
2     cat     dog     2
3   horse     cow     3
4     cow   horse     3
5 chicken   sheep     4
6   sheep chicken     4
```

So essentially, rows 1 and 2 are the same, just with item1 and item2 flip-flopped.  And the same for rows 3 and 4, and rows 5 and 6.

I want the output data frame, after filtering to be:

```
    item1   item2 correlation
1     dog     cat     2
2   horse     cow     3
3 chicken   sheep     4
```

It is not just a simple matter of using unique(), at least that I can figure.

Comment: One thing I forgot to note: the "duplicated" rows are not always on every other row.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-rows-considering-two-columns-in-r-without-order

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using the `sqldf` package.  Assuming you don't care about *which* `correlation` you retain from the duplicates, we can try:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT MIN(item1, item2) AS item1, MAX(item1, item2) AS item2,
               MAX(correlation) AS correlation
        FROM df
        GROUP BY MIN(item1, item2), MAX(item1, item2)"

output <- sqldf(sql)
```

Given that your duplicated rows may not always be adjacent, this `sqldf` option might be useful to you, because in SQL tables are based on unordered records.  So, the adjacent requirement is not a problem.